# Selenium grid is blocking port 4444

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

Currently, I'm trying to run a maven command on Jenkins. After executing a build, I get the error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.codehaus.mojo:selenium-   
maven-plugin:2.1:selenese': Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other    service is.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After getting this, I tried to kill port 4444 by trying to find the process via lsof -t -i:4444, but I wasn't able to find it.

How could I stop selenium from blocking my build?

Comment: What commands have you used for starting your grid?

Comment: The grid is autostarted when I turn on my computer. I guess it's probably a daemon, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: In your selenium test, how are you setting up your browser/driver can you post that code. Also try going to http://localhost:4444/grid and tell us what do you see

Answer (score 1):

You may try this command 
`http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer` in your browser.
If port 4444 is occupied, it will show "OK OK", else it will give error.

But after this, you'll be able to run selenium on port 4444.

I have included this command to run by default before starting my selenium tests, so I do not need to bother about anything running on that port.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work for me (it did for a lot of other people). I fixed it by running ps -ef | grep selenium, and then killing that process.